# Ubuntu does not recognize amd

Tags: 16.04

I am using AMD Radeon ™ HD R7 M265 butUbuntu 16.04 is recognizing as

```
00 : 02.0 VGA compatible controller [ 0300 ] : Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 [ 8086 : 1616 ] (rev 09)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have switchable graphics (integrated and discrete), Ubuntu will use the integrated graphics unless there's a driver installed for the discrete graphics.

In your case, you have Intel and AMD graphics and Ubuntu is using the Intel graphics because you don't have proprietary drivers. In order to use the AMD card, you would have to install `fglrx`.

Unfortunately for you, `fglrx` is no longer supported in 16.04, nor will it work if installed. There is a proprietary driver that is in development, but I don't believe it is very stable.

For now, you'll either have to wait until a proprietary AMD driver comes out for 16.04 or downgrade to 14.04 or 15.10 so you can use `fglrx`.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to read this first !

[Why Radeon Users May Want to Avoid Ubuntu 16.04](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04)

And before you do ,this is the part of the article which will break your heart.

> You can not re-install the fglrx/catalyst driver (or its display stack) from the Ubuntu 16.04 archives after the upgrade completes as the driver is, bluntly, no longer there.
>
> Furthermore, you cannot download and install the fglrx/catalyst driver
>   using binary packages from the AMD website as, even if you could get
>   them to install, the driver does not support Xorg 1.18¹ that ships in
>   Xenial.
>
> To top it all off Canonical say: “AMD won’t support fglrx on 16.04,
>   period”, and Canonical has no desire to take over the duties (which it
>   would have to support for the next five years kids, as this is an
>   LTS).